# How can I solve problem with typescript and @storybook/addon-knobs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I want to use *@storybook/addon-knobs* method *text*. I set this type in my code `type ButtonColor = 'primary' | 'transparent' | 'light'` and I wanna write text in input (text from addon):

```
const ButtonStories = () => (
  <Button
    borderRadius={16}
    color={text('color', 'primary')}
  >
    {text('value', 'Button')}
  </Button>
)
```

But when I use it I get as error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'primary' | 'light' |
> 'transparent' | undefined

How can I fix it?

Comment: change `color={text('color', 'primary')}` to `color='primary'`

Comment: No, you didn't understand. I need to have opportunity change this value in storybook. So I use @storybook/addon-knobs

Comment: aha I understand you now, you actually need a radio not a text, as nothing is preventing the user to enter any string value.
you can however get around type safety by adding `color={text('color', 'primary') as ButtonColor}`

Comment: Let me check if radio supports generic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that text does indeed return a string nothing is constraining the user from entering any value you can however use a radio component instead.

```
// Change ButtonColor where it's defined
enum ButtonColor { primary = 'primary', transparent = 'transparent', light = 'light' }

// use enum values as Array.
const ButtonColors = Object.keys(ButtonColor)

// Or redefine all values as an array
// const ButtonColors = ['primary', 'transparent', 'light']

const ButtonStories = () => (
  <Button
    borderRadius={16}
    color={radio('color', ButtonColors, ButtonColor.primary)}
  >
    {text('value', 'Button')}
  </Button>
)
```

Comment: I solve my problem with select, but I think that your solution will work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) instead, using `as` keyword.

```js
const color = text('color', 'primary') as 'primary' | 'transparent' | 'light'

const ButtonStories = () => (
  <Button
    borderRadius={16}
    color={color}
  >
    {text('value', 'Button')}
  </Button>
)
```